# How to turn an itertools "grouper" object into a list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to learn how to use itertools.groupby in Python and I wanted to find the size of each group of characters. At first I tried to see if I could find the length of a single group:

```
from itertools import groupby
len(list(list( groupby("cccccaaaaatttttsssssss") )[0][1]))
```

and I would get 0 every time.

I did a little research and found out that other people were doing it this way:

```
from itertools import groupby
for key,grouper in groupby("cccccaaaaatttttsssssss"):
    print key,len(list(grouper))
```

Which works great. What I am confused about is why does the latter code work, but the former does not? If I wanted to get only the nth group like I was trying to do in my original code, how would I do that?

Comment: as an aside, just a variation on your idea, if you need to save partitions of your input by Antlr4 channels (I do need to do that), you can do something like `groups = itertools.groupby(tokens.tokens, lambda token: token.channel); groups_lists = [(k, list(grouper)) for k, grouper in groups]`. The list comprehension might be a little faster than a Python loop.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The reason that your first approach doesn't work is that the the groups get "consumed" when you create that list with

```
list(groupby("cccccaaaaatttttsssssss"))
```

To quote from [the `groupby` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying
>   iterable with `groupby()`. Because the source is shared, when the
>   `groupby()` object is advanced, the previous group is no longer
>   visible.

Let's break it down into stages.

```
from itertools import groupby

a = list(groupby("cccccaaaaatttttsssssss"))
print(a)
b = a[0][1]
print(b)
print('So far, so good')
print(list(b))
print('What?!')
```

**output**

```
[('c', <itertools._grouper object at 0xb715104c>), ('a', <itertools._grouper object at 0xb715108c>), ('t', <itertools._grouper object at 0xb71510cc>), ('s', <itertools._grouper object at 0xb715110c>)]
<itertools._grouper object at 0xb715104c>
So far, so good
[]
What?!
```

Our `itertools._grouper object at 0xb715104c` is empty because it shares its contents with the "parent" iterator returned by `groupby`, and those items are now gone because that first `list` call iterated over the parent.

It's really no different to what happens if you try to iterate twice over any iterator, eg a simple generator expression.

```
g = (c for c in 'python')
print(list(g))
print(list(g))
```

**output**

```
['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
[]
```

---

BTW, here's another way to get the length of a `groupby` group if you don't actually need its contents; it's a little cheaper (and uses less RAM) than building a list just to find its length.

```
from itertools import groupby

for k, g in groupby("cccccaaaaatttttsssssss"):
    print(k, sum(1 for _ in g))
```

**output**

```
c 5
a 5
t 5
s 7
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thanks a bunch!