# Unable to retrieve itertools iterators outside list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Consider this:

```
>>> res = [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby('abbba')]                                                                                                                                                           

>>> res                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[['a'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['a']]
```

and then this:

```
>>> res = [g for k,g in itertools.groupby('abbba')]

>>> list(res[0])
[]
```

I'm baffled by this. **Why** do they return different results?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn an itertools "grouper" object into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490079/how-to-turn-an-itertools-grouper-object-into-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is pretty clear that the iterator for the grouper is shared with the `groupby` iterator:

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying
> iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the
> groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.
> So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list...

The reason you are getting empty lists as that the iterator is already consumed by the time you are trying to iterate over it.

```
import itertools 

res = [g for k,g in itertools.groupby('abbba')]

next(res[0])
# Raises StopIteration:
```